# AWS Cloudformation logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using AWS CDK to subscribe Lambda function for Create events from S3. I receive this kind of error.

```
Error: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations. See the details in CloudWatch Log 
Stream: 2023/11/13/[$LATEST]b53fbfb27fc4405082109cabad91f3ce (RequestId: 1b65e732-7a5e-476e-9494-9ddde24654f0)
```

The same error I see in the Cloudformation stack. The problem is in CloudWatch. I cannot find the log group related to the Cloudformation. Do you know how to find it? What is its name pattern? Can it be configured somewhere in the Cloudformation settings? We have hundreds of groups, so I cannot go through the list and check every single one

I tried to search that log group using different patterns but no success. I just need those logs to understand what's wrong with my stack and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yor issue is probably related to the missing Lambda Invocation Parmissions.
Check yor template for AWS::Lambda::Permission
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html

Make sure (I have no idea how to do it with CDK) that Permission is granted before PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation.

BTW, Cloudformation logs are available in Cloudformation stack in events Tab.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer. Read the question carefully. I am not looking for the permission fix, because I am able to add that event source without CDK. I don't want to do that because the aim is to automate the deployment. Also I am not looking for Cloudformation logs, because I copied the error message from there, so I know where they are. I am looking for the Cloudwatch log group and stream from Cloudformation error message. I cannot find it. That's the problem here

Comment: You can check you Lambda log group (the one you are trying to add in PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation.

Another place to check is AWS Cloud Trail.
You can filter events by event name "CreateLogStream". Event details shows StreamId and LogGroup name

Comment: Yes, it helped. I found those logs using CloudTrail. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the log group name?

Comment: the pattern mostly depends on your stack, but in 2 words - search for 'BucketNotificationsHandl'(yes, without 'er') in Cloudwatch and you will find all of them, because the log group is different every time

Comment: Good to know, thanks :)